# priority issues in css

Tags: css

Sorry for the lack of precision in the title, I didn't really know what to write.

the html :

```
<div id="blabla">
  hello
  <span class="red">hello2</span>
</div>
```

the css :

```
#blabla{
  color: black;
}

#blabla:hover{
  color: white;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

I want the string "hello2" to go white when the mouse is over the div "blabla". In the current state, it stays red.

I've tried anything I could think of and didn't manage to do it, I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
#blabla:hover .red {
  color: white;
}
```

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4xhqc/

The problem is even though the selector `#blabla:hover` is more specfic than `.red`, `.red` is applied on the element in question itself - that makes it take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I actually didn't knew you could write something after the :hover

Comment: I was going to mention that in the answer, as I thought you didn't know. The trick is to think of `XYZ:hover` and `XYZ` as two different elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your final CSS rule to:

```
#blabla:hover span.red {
  color: white;
}
```

The problem you're facing is that your rules for div `blabla` bind tighter than the span rule (i.e. those rules are more specific). See the CSS tutorial at BrainJar.com ["Using Style Sheets"](http://www.brainjar.com/css/using/default4.asp) for more info on rule specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the Span elements hover change:

```
#blabla{
  color: black;
}

#blabla:hover{
  color: white;
}

#blabla span:hover{
  color: white;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

If you want all elements in that div to go white then use the * selector, however the implementation of specifying each element at time makes more sense.

Comment: you could also separte two selctors by a comma, getting something like this: `#blabla:hover, #blabla:hover .red´ This way you would only have to declare the properties once, and it makes updating the code much easier